# Judge whether the date cell is within the range according to the current cell

Tags: python, pandas

How to judge whether the date cell is within the range from 08:00 of the previous day (excluded) to 08:00 of the cell day (included) according to the date cell time, and calculate the sum of data in the corresponding range.

original data:

| date | data |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 07:00 | 1 |
| 2022-02-01 09:00 | 2 |
| 2022-02-01 14:00 | 1 |
| 2022-02-01 23:00 | 3 |
| 2022-02-02 09:00 | 1 |
| 2022-02-03 10:00 | 2 |
| 2022-02-04 11:50 | 3 |

result data:

| date | data |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 08:00 | 1 |
| 2022-02-02 08:00 | 6 |
| 2022-02-03 08:00 | 1 |
| 2022-02-04 08:00 | 2 |
| 2022-02-05 08:00 | 3 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df1 = df.astype({'date':'datetime64[ns]'})\
    .resample('D',offset='8h',label='right',
              closed='right',on='date')\
    .sum()
```

| date | data |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 08:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-02-02 08:00:00 | 6 |
| 2022-02-03 08:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-02-04 08:00:00 | 2 |
| 2022-02-05 08:00:00 | 3 |

Comment: This is answered by pandas teacher Li Qinghui(李庆辉).I just copied the code.